# Studying numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods

Is there a book which I can self-study numerical methods needed in engineering and which proves results rigorously? I would like to learn engineering mathematics needed in every day life as well as prove the methods.

Comment: Are you by chance german? I know a very good book for this scenario, but it is written in german.

Comment: @Thomas What is the book?

Comment: Since this was 8 years ago, I am not sure if this is the book, but likely it was: Numerik für Ingenieure und Naturwissenschaftler by Dahmen and Reusken